# How to call class variables and methods inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, attributes

I have a class as follows:

```
class Chips():

    def __init__(self,total=100):
        self.total=total
        self.bet=0
    
    def win_bet(self):
        self.total+=self.bet
    
    def lose_bet(self):
        self.total-=self.bet
```

Now I want to use the attributes of this class self.bet and self.total inside a function as follows:

```
def take_bet():

    while True:
        try:
            self.bet=int(input('Enter the amount of chips you want to bet: '))
            
        except:
            print ('Enter a valid integer value')
            continue
        
        else:
            if (self.bet>self.total):
                print ('You do not have enough chips. You have {}'.format(self.total))
            else:
                break
```

I know it is not right way to call the attributes of the class inside the function. So, what is the correct way to do it? And also what is the way to call methods of the class inside the function?

Comment: Is `take_bet` a part of the class? If not, you'd need to pass in an instance of `Chips`, just like you're doing with the methods, or refer to a global instance of the class from within the function.

Comment: "But I don't want to do it that way." So you don't want to have any instance of the class, and at the same time use a function (and not a method of the class, if I understand what you mean correctly) that makes use of the attributes of an instance??

Comment: No, take_bet is not the part of this class. It is a separate function. What instance do I need to pass in it?

Comment: No what I mean is that, is there any way to create the instance of this class by passing it as the argument of the function. I don't want to create the instance separately.

Comment: You'd create an instance outside of the function and pass it in as an argument, or create it inside the function and `return` it to the caller so they can use it. If you need an instance of a class, you need to create it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in order to do this, you should change the declaration of `take_bet` to something like `take_bet(chips)` to make it accepting a `Chips` instance. So, you'll need to specify a `Chips` instance wherever `take_bet` method is called.

So, your method will look like this:

```py
def take_bet(chips):
    while True:
        try:
            chips.bet=int(input('Enter the amount of chips you want to bet: '))
            
        except:
            print ('Enter a valid integer value')
            continue
        
        else:      
            if (chips.bet>chips.total):
                print ('You do not have enough chips. You have {}'.format(chips.total))
            else:
                break

take_bet(Chips()) # Call example
```

PS: It's better practice to have setters and getters instead of accessing the class variables directly.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: The Pythonic way is to avoid getters and setters, and to use attributes directly. If you need validation, you can use a `property`, and reference attributes as you normally would.